# Graph representation of Keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

What's the best way to get a graph representation of a Keras model that can be manipulated. Specifically, I'm looking for something very similar to the [model_to_dot](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b36436b087bd8e8701ef51718179037cccdfc26e/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/vis_utils.py#L70) function that un-nests nested modules, but instead that returns all the layers as nodes (instead of just their names and dimensions) with an edgelist. The goal is not to visualise the network but instead to create an augmented network based on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TensorBoard utility. Specifically, when training your network, add this callback:

```
            callbacks = []
            callbacks.append(tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir="some_directory", histogram_freq=1))
            model.fit(train,
            epochs=EPOCHS,
            steps_per_epoch=int(train_size / BATCH_SIZE),
            validation_data=val,
            validation_steps=int(val_size / BATCH_SIZE),
            validation_freq=1,
            callbacks=callbacks)
```

Once training is finished, run the command `tensorboard --logdir some_directory` from command line or in jupyter notebook. You can also visualize everything as training proceeds. Along with other information, there is a utility that shows your network as a directed graph.
[TensorBoard Start Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/get_started#using_tensorboard_with_keras_modelfit)